# Clear strings from process memory

Tags: c++, memory

To improve the security of my application, I am trying to delete string data from the process memory, but since there is little information about this on the Internet, I could not write a working code.

Can anyone help me?

My pasted code:

```
void MemoryStringsClear() {
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    char* addr = 0;

    while (VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
    {
        if (mbi.State != MEM_COMMIT || mbi.Protect == PAGE_NOACCESS)
        {
            //char* buffer = new char[mbi.RegionSize];

            //ReadProcessMemory(hProc, addr, buffer, mbi.RegionSize, nullptr);
            if (addr) {
                cout << "Addr: " << &addr << " is cleared!" << endl;
                memset(addr, '0', mbi.RegionSize);
            }
            
        }
        addr += mbi.RegionSize;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProc);
}
```

**EDITED:**
I chose this way of solving the problem because my application consists of many modules (.exe applications), some of which I cannot change.

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to just store any sensitive strings in a class which clears its memory on destruction?

Comment: What makes you think that this string data is not required for application to run properly? Anyway, this looks like an XY problem.

Comment: @AlanBirtles No, due to the specifics of my application.

Comment: @user7860670 Because in the code my program no longer uses anything like that, but since the program was not terminated, the destructor was not called.

Comment: Why delete them? What if you need them again? This can be achieved but, not the way you do it. It's very ugly/hacky method and takes a long time to process. The simpler, better solution is to encrypt them. Checkout my article: https://mecanik.dev/en/posts/runtime-encrypted-strings-part-1/

Comment: @Mecanik I cannot comment on your article (captcha keeps reappearing, Firefox 119.0), so I comment here: Since string constants in C++ are nothing but `char` arrays, you need not single out every character in section 4.2.

Comment: @Iziminza Thank you for reporting the issue with the captcha, I really appreciate it! I have now replaced it because the issue is from their end. Feel free to try and comment anytime again. Regarding your comment here, I am not entirely sure what you are referring to. All strings remain visible in memory unless you clear them.

Comment: @Iziminza Your method will leave the original string in memory, whilst in my method each character will be compiled as actual bytes ;)

Comment: A string in memory is nothing different than an array of individual bytes. Besides, this only refers to the program that you use to encrypt the strings, not the program that those will be used in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with your approach (my idea for a solution is further down):

### Most of the strings listed are environment variables

All of the programs that run on your computer have access to those. They are copied to the memory space of every program on startup so every program knows where to look for certain files. There is no point in removing them from the memory of your application, since every application running on your computer already knows them.

You can see them by running `cmd.exe`, typing `set` and then pressing `return`.

### `OpenProcess` and `VirtualQueryEx` are for accessing another process

You could simply use `VirtualQuery`, since you only want to access your own process.

I guess you are trying to get access to non-committed memory pages by doing this, but `memset` can only access committed, writable memory pages in your own program's address space. So those two approaches don't mix.

But there is a more important point to this:

### Non-committed memory does not exist

If a memory page is not committed, there is no actual memory assigned to that address. That means, that there is nothing you can overwrite with zeroes. The memory containing your strings may already have been assigned to another application. Read some information about virtual memory management for details.

### Most calls to `free`, `delete` or garbage collection do not always actually decommit the page

For efficiency reasons, when your code allocates and deallocates memory, your runtime library hands you down little scraps of a larger page of memory (called "heap") that is only decommitted if every single piece in it has been freed.

You could find freed blocks of memory by walking over the heap entries, but how that works depends on your C runtime library or other runtime libraries.

### The operating system might move your strings around

If the operating systems detects that there is a shortage of memory, it can save your strings to disk to free up memory for other applications, and reloads them when your application again becomes active. It usually does not bother to clean the disk up afterwards. You have no influence on that (unless you format your hard drive).

---

### My ideas for a solution

Before every call to `free` or `delete` in your code that frees
memory with sensitive information (and only those), you can call
`memset(...)` on that single block of memory. In C++, you can wrap that up in a class which clears its memory on destruction, as Alan Birtles pointed out in his comment.

I don't think there is a solution that you can simply pop onto an existing program that clears sensitive information after the memory has been freed.

This approach leaves only the last problem. You can only circumvent that if you never store your sensitive information unencrypted in memory. That is probably not feasible since that would mean that you do not handle it only encrypted.

### What will be difficult or impossible

If you want to clear freed memory in other processes (the separate *.exe files you cannot change you refer to in your edit), you have to understand the internal heap layout of those and use `WriteProcessMemory` instead of `memset`.

But this does not catch the case where the other program actually decommits a page, since you do not know if the operating system has already reassigned it. When this happens is completely outside of your control.

You might also try to reimplement the `free` and `delete` functions in your C runtime library so they first clear the memory and then call the original version, but this only works if they are actually used by those *.exe files and they are dynamically linked. If these conditions are met, you might still have a hard time.

Comment: Your answer partially solves my problem, so I edited my question to add some notes.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. To be honest, I think this is just too hard to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

## Define the security threats you want to protect against

> To improve the security of my application,

What exactly are you trying to guard against? Have you verified that clearing process memory will actually work against the security attacks that you want to defend against?

## Know how memory works

Find out how your operating system allocates both virtual and physical memory, otherwise wrong assumptions of how it works might cause you to implement ineffective solutions. Most computers systems use [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), which means some of your memory might actually end up being copied to different places in physical RAM or to disk. On the other hand, if your process exits and a new process starts, most operating systems will clear the RAM used by the first process before assigning it to the second.

## Ensure you have full control over the memory you want to clear

As Iziminza already mentioned, your process has virtual memory, but the operating system can choose how to back that virtual memory with physical memory. When it needs RAM for some other process, it can decide to move your data to a swap file on disk until it is needed again. In order to make clearing of memory using `memset()` meaningful, you must ensure there are no copies stored elsewhere. You can do this by using [`VirtualLock()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtuallock) on Windows, or [`mlock()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) on other operating systems. Even then, if the computer is going into [hibernation mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_(computing)), even locked memory is written to disk.

Comment: Very good idea! I completely forgot that `VirtualLock` even existed. Unfortunately, I guess that even this fails if you put your computer into hibernation (or the hybrid standby present since Windows 7), since then all memory contents are saved to disk.

Comment: My application communicates with the server, so I need to hide some important string data from programs like "ProcessHacker" and the like.

Comment: @Iziminza Good point, I forgot about that!

Comment: @GishReloaded Ah, well if ProcessHacker can read the memory of other processes, then there is really not much you can do. Clearing memory after use will reduce the time window where ProcessHacker could be used to read your secrets, but it is never made impossible.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Anyway, I think it's better than nothing.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I found `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` > `Protect ` > `MEM_PRIVATE` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-memory_basic_information) Maybe this will help to check. It is written there **"Indicates that the memory pages within the region are private (that is, not shared by other processes)."**;

Comment: @GishReloaded Yes, but be careful with that way of thinking. It greatly reduces the chance of someone starting ProcessHacker at some random point in time from seeing the secrets, but for an attacker who *wants* to those secrets, it will not do much to prevent them from getting those secrets.

Comment: `MEM_PRIVATE` means not *actively* shared with other processes, but another process that has access to the memory space of your process will still be able to read it. Otherwise, debuggers would not be able to work.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I understand that this is a very bad way to protect against good hackers, fortunately, this is not the last step to hacking my entire program. Therefore, I still want to confuse novice lamers.