# Hiding SQL queries from applications similar to Process Hacker

Tags: c++, sql, ssms

Currently I'm debugging an issue where the sql queries executed by an Application are visible in ProcessHacker 2 [ Steps - Open ProcessHacker -> Right Click on the application -> Properties -> Strings -> Filter -> Type Any keyword that will be present in a query i.e., for ex. Select *.
I read this article on a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67955877/clear-strings-from-process-memory
The sql queries are stored in the application code.
One thing I observed that whenever the query logs are written, the Process Hacker was able to access it and display in its Strings option.
I tried clearing the logs once its purpose was done but still the old queries were visible.
Is the ProcessHacker able to access the query strings from SSMS?
How does ProcessHacker able to extract such strings?
Any way to resolve this issue?

Tried clearing the logs once its usage was over, thinking that the processhacker will not be able to access it.

Update - Clearing logs it worked in a single machine setup, but if the SSMS and the application are in two different boxes/vm's , the queries are visible again. What can I do now??

Comment: If you encode the strings somehow and store the encoded strings in the executable and then decrypt them just as you execute the statement and then clear the variable just after they will only be in memory while the query is being executed.  Even that might not be enough - some queries take quite a while to execute so they might still be picked up...

Comment: I suggest that you keep SQL queries in some encrypted file. In your application, decrypt the file and read the queries.

Comment: Someone could just spin of profiler or an extended event if they wanted to see the queries running on an instance; stopping a program seeing what the queriew are in another program isn't going to stop that. This all smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: _"Any way to resolve this issue?"_ - Nope. It really isn't feasible to try to "protect" SQL queries; even if they're encrypted or encoded within your application you'll always be able to get them from the RDBMS via tracing or a debugger, so it's a waste of your time to try.

Comment: I Tried clearing the logs generated at that instance. Seems like its working

Comment: Isn't this one of the reasons for using stored procedures?